# Как исправить ошибку заимствования в Rust?

Tags: rust, виртуальная-машина, байткод

Пытаюсь написать простую виртуальную машину (интерпретатор байткода):

```
const STACK_SIZE: usize = 1000;

mod errors;
mod opcodes;
mod utils;

struct Registers {
    ...
}

struct Machine<'a> {
    registers: Registers,
    stack:     [u64, STACK_SIZE],
    code:      &'a [u8]
}

impl<'a> Machine<'a> {
    pub fn new(...) {
        ...
    }

    pub fn fetch(&mut self) -> Result<u8, errors::RuntimeError> {
        if ... {
            let next = self.code[self.position()];
            ...
            Ok(next)
        } else {
            Err(errors::RuntimeError::EndOfCode)
        }
    }

    pub fn fetch_many(&mut self) -> Result<&[u8], errors::RuntimeError> {
        if ... {
            let bytes = &self.code[self.position()..self.position() + n];
            ...
            Ok(bytes)
        } else {
            Err(errors::RuntimeError::EndOfCode)
        }
    }

    pub fn position(&self) -> usize {
        ...
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        loop {
            let instruction = self.fetch().expect("unexpected end of code");
            match instruction {
                instruction if instruction == opcodes::Opcode::Push as u8 => {
                    let bytes = self.fetch_many(8).expect("unexpected end of code");
                    let operand = utils::pack_bytes(bytes);
                    self.stack[self.registers.stack_pointer as usize] = operand;
                    self.registers.stack_pointer -= 1;
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Проблема в функции `run`. Когда пытаюсь скомпилировать код, выдаёт следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
src/main.rs:63:21: 63:80 error: cannot assign to `self.stack[..]` because it is borrowed [E0506]
src/main.rs:63                     self.stack[self.registers.stack_pointer as usize] = operand;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:61:33: 61:37 note: borrow of `self.stack[..]` occurs here
src/main.rs:61                     let bytes = self.fetch_many(8).expect("end of code");
                                               ^~~~
src/main.rs:63:32: 63:60 error: cannot use `self.registers.stack_pointer` because it was mutably borrowed [E0503]
src/main.rs:63                     self.stack[self.registers.stack_pointer as usize] = operand;
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:61:33: 61:37 note: borrow of `*self` occurs here
src/main.rs:61                     let bytes = self.fetch_many(8).expect("end of code");
                                               ^~~~
src/main.rs:64:21: 64:54 error: cannot assign to `self.registers.stack_pointer` because it is borrowed [E0506]
src/main.rs:64                     self.registers.stack_pointer -= 1;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:61:33: 61:37 note: borrow of `self.registers.stack_pointer` occurs here
src/main.rs:61                     let bytes = self.fetch_many(8).expect("end of code");
                                               ^~~~
```

Перечитал разделы документации про владение (ownership) и заимствование (borrowing), но всё равно не понял, что конкретно у меня не так.

Comment: А `fetch_many` делает запись где-то? Зачем ему мутабельная ссылка?

Comment: @D-side да, `fetch_many` меняет `self.registers`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fetch_many` возвращает ссылку на срез из `self`, так что, пока эта ссылка (сохраняемая в переменной `bytes`) жива, объект нельзя менять.

Как вариант решения - возвращать из `fetch_many` не срез, а скопированное значение (например, `[u8; 8]`).

Или, в данном конкретном примере, можно ограничить время жизни переменной `bytes`:

```
let operand = {
    let bytes = self.fetch_many(8).expect("unexpected end of code");
    utils::pack_bytes(bytes)
};
```

Comment: В моём случае возвращать массив заранее известной длины не получится, потому что суть функции `fetch_many` как раз в том, что она возвращает произвольное число байт. А вот вариант с ограничением времени жизни переменной `bytes` сработал, спасибо.

Comment: Классный способ. Тем временем, в Rust предлагают сделать [partial borrowing](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1215), заимствование отдельных полей структуры.